Connect device using WebUSB and Flutter
I'm trying to connect a device using WebUSB and Flutter.
But I get this error when trying to connect:
NetworkError: Failed to execute 'claimInterface' on 'USBDevice': Unable to claim interface.

The code in JavaScript:
async function requestADBDevice() {
try {
    const device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [] });
    await device.open();
    await device.selectConfiguration(1);
    await device.claimInterface(0);
    console.log('Device connected:', device);

    window.adbDevice = device;

    return device;
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error: ' + error);
}

}

On what platforms do you hit this issue with (e.g. MacOS, Windows)? Does this happen on Android devices you have tried?

@JackHsieh I figured out what the issue was, I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and it appeared that adb kill-server didn't kill the ADB process. This was starting it self again but after terminating it, it worked. Probably the Jetbrains Toolbox launched it every time I closed it.
